# Transfer composer files from localhost to server

Tags: php, composer-php, stripe-payments

I am using localhost as my development server in which I added Composer and installed the Stripe dependencies.

Since I have a shared hosting account, I want to transfer the Composer files to my server since I don't have root access to run the Composer install locally.

Which files do I move, and where do I put them? I have moved `composer.json` `composer.lock` and the `vendor` folder into my sites root directory with all of my sites files and folders.

However, when I go to run a Stripe command I get errors in which I have to include each file in the directory. Obviously, Composer is not correct on the new server since I have to include each file.

How can I get it so that Composer works properly on the new server?

Comment: Can you post your error? Are you sure it doesn't have to do with auto loader itself

Comment: I quite literally moved the files onto the new server. I did not receive an error, but rather that the Stripe class isn't available since I did not include it. Therefore, Composer isn't working. I never installed it on the new server. Is this required for it to work? I thought I read differently somewhere..

Comment: Yes, it needs to be install on server. Are you running a linux server?

Comment: Yes, but it is a shared server

Comment: then try:  php composer-setup.php --install-dir={your directory}--filename=composer .  This way it is install in that directory and not globally

Comment: Copying the vendor folder including autoloading files is enough, because Composer's Autoloading is not bound to a fixed location and should work. It seems to be a packaging (dependency included?) or autoloading issue. Please post your `composer.json` and the autoloading related code of your application. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need root access to use Composer. Just download (or transfer from your local machine) `composer.phar` and use it on the server.

About copying: I advice to copy the whole project directory as is (with all `src`, `vendor`, `bin` dirs and other file). It's in your interests to make local and remote environments the same.